# in-line JS setTimeOut does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with a piece of in-line JavaScript in Firefox. It's s simple `SetTimeout()` method within an `<a>` element that sets a delay (to allow time for an animation to play out) before opening the destination link in question.

**The Problem:**
When I click on the link in Firefox I get taken to a white page with the number 2 in the top left hand corner of the screen.

**Other Browsers:**
Opera, Chrome, Edge, AVG Secure Browser - all work as expected and open the destination link as expected.

**The Code:**
I've stripped down the code to the bare minimum in order to isolate the problem and realise that it is the in-line JS within the link that Firefox does not like (or is completely ignoring!) Whatever it is, I get no warnings or exceptions thrown when looking in FF developer tools.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <p id="homepage">
        <a
          href="javascript:setTimeout(()=>{window.location = './index.html'},500);"
          >Home</a
        >
      </p>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

At first we thought this could be an IDE problem or server related issue but those possibilities have been eliminated.

Has anyone seen this problem before or know why I'm encountering this purely in Firefox?

Comment: Can you try to replace the lambda with a classic function?

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply, however, I get the same result using classic function syntax, but only in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#javascript_uris)

> When a browser follows a javascript: URI, it evaluates the code in the URI and then replaces the contents of the page with the returned value, unless the returned value is undefined. The void operator can be used to return undefined

Like suggested, try using the `void` operator:

```
<a href="javascript:void(setTimeout(()=>{window.location = './index.html'},500));">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You are using an arrow function syntax which is not standardized among all browsers apparently. Also is not backwards compatible and you should either use a compiler such as Babel, or either write classical functions syntax style code.</strike>

UPDATE: just use this code if you want it to work.

```
  <p id="homepage">
    <a
      href="index.html" onclick="window.setTimeout(function(){window.location = './index.html'},500); return false"
      >Home</a
    >
  </p>
```

Comment: I so wish that had worked, however, I still get the same result, a white page with the number 2 in the top left corner of the page. Just Firefox!

Comment: The inline code you were using was not correct. try this: use href for the actual target but do cancel the event using the attached method.